# Submit a POST variable with Javascript?

Tags: javascript

Is there anyway to submit a POST variable, with name, to another page? I.e. form submission, as IF a button were clicked, but without having to click a button.

Comment: yes, take a look at this thread:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/133925/javascript-post-request-like-a-form-submit

Answer (score 2):

There are many ways to do this - the easiest, library-free method probably being something like:

If your HTML looks like this (has at least the id, method, and action attributes)

```
<form id="myForm" method="post" action="post-target.php">
   <input type="hidden" name="username" value="username" />
</form>
```

You can submit the form via javascript like this:

```
myForm = document.getElementById('myForm');
myForm.submit();
```

Comment: Yes, but I want the specific information contained in the button to be sent, too. I.e. I want to send a POST variable with the name "del" over to another page.

Answer (score 0):

Yes: you could for example use jQuery to tie a JavaScript function to a button's `onclick` event. And then call the click() function on the button in the jQuery `ready` function.